# Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange signature

Tags: java, ssl

I'm using

```
 new XmlSlurper().parse('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')
```

to get the €/Dollar in a tomcat web application. My jdk is OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Debian)

the first time the method don't get any error but after a lot of time i receive this error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Invalid ECDH ServerKeyExchange
>   signature

Any solution without change java version?